# Call javascript on end loading page

Tags: javascript

How to call javascript function at the end of loading page ? I add  at the end of page, but is there any other way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using [jquery](http://jquery.com/), you can use [`ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Answer (score 5):

Use [onload](http://onlinetools.org/articles/unobtrusivejavascript/chapter4.html)

Answer (score 2):

Adding it to the end is actually wrong because of the way it may behave with different browsers.

You should add it to the onload event of the body tag.

e.g

```
<body onload="DoAfterPageLoad()">
```